# Impossible to get a css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've encount a problem with my jQuery code.

I have some properties in a class in my css, like this :

```
aside#rubrique nav li.li-bleu p.p-niv1{

   border-right : 2px solid black;
}
```

I can change the border-color like this :

```
$('aside#rubrique nav li.li-bleu p.p-niv1').css("border-right", "2px solid red");
```

But I need to get the color value of the border, I do that, but the javascript alert displays nothing :

```
alert($('aside#rubrique nav li.li-bleu p.p-niv1').css("border-right"));
```

Is not possible to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value directly from the css (i.e. there is no html element with this style)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
alert($('aside#rubrique nav li.li-bleu p.p-niv1').css('border-right-color'));
```

Answer (score 3):

border-right is a shorthand way of setting border-width-right, border-style-right and border-color-right, so to access the individual property you would use

```
alert($('aside#rubrique nav li.li-bleu p.p-niv1').css("border-right-color"));
```

[You might find this reference useful](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-right)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
var borderRight = $('aside#rubrique nav li.li-bleu p.p-niv1').css("border-right");
alert(borderRight.split(/\s+/).pop());
```

Or you can use "border-right-color" property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alert(document.getElementById("rubrique").style.borderRight);
```